# What's the best way to capture information on every action in java?

Tags: java, logging

Suppose you want to capture the page source of a web application on every action, e.g.

```
public void click() {
    getPageSource();
}

public void type() {
    getPageSource();
}

public void select() {
    getPageSource();
}
```

I have to call getPageSource() in every function, but is there a neater way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're working in a Java Web Application, you should create a [Filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) to intercept every request made in the application. Here is a sample:

Java Class

```
package edu.home;

import javax.servlet.*;

public class MyFilter implements Filter {

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("New request in the application!");
        //here you can add getPageSource() and send request/response
    }
}
```

Configure the Filter in web.xml

```html
<!--declare the filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>edu.home.FISesionExpirada</filter-class>
</filter>
<!-- declare where the filter should be used -->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Things like these are typically called [cross-cutting concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern) and they don't fit well into the object oriented framework.  The simple answer is that, in plain old Java, there really isn't a better way to do this.

There are solutions, but they aren't widely used in my experience, see e.g.,
http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/

Answer (score 0):

See if your web application framework supports filters, or listeners, or observers, or interceptors, or some kind of aspect-oriented programming. The kind of problem you describe has been solved many times, surely in your particular development environment you'll find a solution.